# Rapid Miner Correlation Table

Tags: rapidminer

I'm trying to produce a correlation table of two nominal attributes from a clustered dataset (Ripley). I'm striving for a correlation table of [label]:[cluster]. My problem is that the attributes are shown as "?" in the correlation table. Anybody knows?

[correlation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2S4V.png)

[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD2w2.png)

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHPNc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated attribute `cluster` is a nominal attribute. The `Correlation Matrix` operator calculates the Pearson correlation coefficient, which cannot be computed for nominal (=discrete) attributes, thus the correlation is unknown ("missing", displayed as a `?`).

Comment: Thanks! I converted the attributes to numerical and now I got my correlation table.

Comment: @jeffsummoner Please note, that converting the discrete `cluster` attribute to a numerical attribute introduces problems, since the now numerical values are arbitrarily sorted and now have a mathematical link - "2" is twice as important as "1". If you would assign the numbers differently to the discrete cluster attribute, the correlation would change drastically. With that method you only calculate the correlation to arbitrary numbers.